# "What client do you start with?" Vs. "Do you start with which client?"

Tags: difference, syntax

A seller sees that 2 customers enter his store. Now, his small child wants to ask his father who is the first client to get service. Are both sentences equal or only the first is natural?

> 1. Daddy, which client do you start with?
> 2. Daddy, do you start with which client?

Comment: It's spelled **Daddy**

Comment: Only the first one is correct.

Comment: **edited**... you should install a spell checker on your browser. If you're typing on a mobile, deactivate the predictive text. It messes up more things than not.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I do have a spelling checker on my PC. I don't use predictive text, never. In this specific case, it was an anagram as you can see...

Answer (score 3):

1. It should probably be **Daddy**, not Dadi.
2. Someone who enters a store to buy something is a **customer**, not a client. Clients typically buy professional services or something similar. For example, a consulting firm has clients; a sports agent has clients; Wal-Mart has customers.
3. The first question is correct:

> **Daddy**, which **customer** do you start with?

4. If you wanted to say "Do you start with...." as you have in the second question, you would have to specifically refer to one of the customers. But you don't have enough information to do that, so you can't use the second question at all.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the other answers, that the first is grammatical, but anomalous for several reasons.

But I want to explain why the second is not grammatical.

In questions without a question word, we normally invert the subject and verb/auxiliary:

> **Do you** see him?

> **Can you** get there on time?

You may have met a rule that where there is a question word, we invert unless the question word is the subject:

> Where **did he** go?

but

> Who went there?

But that rule isn't the whole story. More accurately, we invert if there's a question word and the subject doesn't come first. So in the example just above we don't invert, because the subject (Who) comes first, but we do in the previous example, because the subject (he) does not come first.

But while non-subject question words usually come first, they don't always have to. One usage where they don't is when the question is a rhetorical question expressing surprise or disbelief:

> You went **where**?

> They told you **what**??

So your second sentence would be more normally

> Which client do you start with? (with inversion)

but to express surprise or disbelief

> You started with **which** client? (no inversion).

What we don't do, (and why your sentence is ungrammatical) is invert when the question word is not before the verb.

Answer (score 1):

Both are "wrong".

Firstly small children don't care which person "daddy" serves first. Children don't use words like "client". They don't understand the notion of a professional relationship. A child would not ask this question.

The first would be possible for an adult to say (if you remove "Dadi/Daddy"). The second is grammatically incorrect. But small children make grammar mistakes all the time.

If you are writing fiction, rethink how your small child will act. If not, don't try to talk like a small child.

Comment: 1+ mainly for your humor.